# easeInOutQuad with a fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have searched for a couple hours now and cant seem to find the correct solution to this.  I need to fade in a background image after its loaded.  The loading and fadeIn() works with the code i have pasted but it is choppy.  So i want to use `easeInOutQuad` with `fadeIn()` to see if its smoother. (the reason it is choppy is because there is other script at work doing other things at the same time).I tried this:

```
$(".wings-wrapper").fadeIn(2000, 'easeInOutQuad', function(){});
```

But it did not work .

```
var backgroundImage = $(currentWing).data("background-url");

        var bgimage = new Image();

        bgimage.src = backgroundImage;       

        $(bgimage).load(function(){

            $(".wings-wrapper").css("background-image","url("+$(this).attr("src")+")").fadeIn(1000);

        });
```

Comment: PS Say how i can improve my questions if you dont like it as I would like to get better at asking...Thanks again!  Jason

Comment: do you want to fadein/out the image after it is loaded or after each hover ?

Comment: I need it to fade in on the page load only.

Comment: Got it, You are actually trying to fadeIn an element when its already loaded. To create a fadeIn effect, hide the image first..and then apply jQuery's `fadeIn()` with a  delay. I've added an answer. Please check :)

Comment: I found this page which does exactly what i would like but it doesnt display any code.  It uses fadIn() with easeInOutQuad    http://matthewlein.com/experiments/easing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking to load an image with fade-in effect.

You may do this either with javascript or with CSS

**Javascript:**

Simply hide the image once loaded and use `fadeIn()` to make it appear again with a fade effect.

`$(".jsfade").hide(0).delay(500).fadeIn(3000)`

Where `.jsfade` is the class attached to an image

**CSS:**

You can also use CSS animations to change the opacity of the image to create a  fadeIn effect. For an image with .fade class,

```
  <img src="image.jpg" class="fade" />
```

You can define the css classes as follows

```
.fade {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
}


@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.fade:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

jQuery UI specifies the following signature for `show/hide/fadeIn` functions

```
.show( [duration,] [easing,] [callback] )
```

Having said that, following is the code with different *easing* options

```
 $(".jsfade").fadeIn(3000, 'linear')  //WITH LINEAR AS EASING OPTION
 $(".jsfadeEaseinOutQuad").fadeIn(3000,'easeInOutQuad') //with easeInOutQuad as the easing option.
```

So, the reason why `$(".wings-wrapper").fadeIn(2000, 'easeInOutQuad', function(){});` doesnt seem to work is because your *content is probably already visible* and hence fadeIn() will essentially do nothing. To See the effect, *you need to hide the elements first and then apply the fadeIn()*.

Use the css property `display:none` to hide `.wings-wrapper`

Here's the UPDATED [**plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/bE4vyzp88gYE24GvGr7r?p=preview) with both approaches.

Comment: Thanks nln!  But as i mentioned...the fade code i have works...What i need though is to use fadein with an easeInOutQuad from jquery ui.  I cant use css in this case.

Comment: @Jason: I have updated the answer with more details. Also, please see updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bE4vyzp88gYE24GvGr7r?p=preview) and notice the difference between both easing(linear and easeInOutQuad)

Comment: Ill try this...Thank you again...Sorry, i forgot to show the code above that does hide it.  $(".wings-wrapper").hide();